# How to show dates on the basis of comparing two different array lists inside a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to show Ticks(green tick as in the screenshot) on comparing two ArrayList in a recyclerView.
[image]

The first ArrayList (**List1**) contains **all the dates**:

```
List1 = [2022-02-21,2022-02-22,2022-02-23 2022-02-24, 2022-02-25, 2022-03-10]
```

The second ArrayList (**List2**) contains **only the dates which upon matching with List1 will enable the green tick**:

```
List2 = [2022-02-21,2022-02-22]
```

This is how I am comparing it in my Adapter class :

```
   for (int j = 0; j < List1.size(); j++) {
            if (List1.get(j).trim().equalsIgnoreCase(List2.get(position).trim())) {
                holder.greenTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {
                holder.greenTick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
```

The problem is that all the Ticks are visible. The matching of ArrayList is not working.

Comment: A simple way to debug this is to add a `Log.i(TAG, "At pos %d and for j %d, List1(j)=%s and List2(position)=%s", position, j, List1.get(j), List2.get(position));` inside your `for`, before the `if`. I suspect the `for` should be done by List2.

Comment: I cannot understand your comment. How will this hide the ticks? Please elaborate a little

Comment: I do know what a log is, but I am asking for a solution buddy, if you can provide one

Comment: I tried an answer, but the Log output would have helped me (and others) to be sure to give you the right answer, that's why I asked you to do it. You should also post more of your getView() method in you recycler adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you use List1 to show all the dates in the recycler, then `position` in your code is probably the adapter item position for each date square you got from List1.
You then want to compare each item with the values in List2 to know if you should show the tick or not.

So the comparison should be something like

```
for (int j = 0; j < List2.size(); j++) {
            if ("Adapter item at position".equalsIgnoreCase(List2.get(j).trim())) {
                holder.greenTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.greenTick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please let me know, what is : Adapter item at position  ? How can I get it

Comment: Please post more code from your getView method(what you do before the lines you posted), the item is the one you used to show the date text in the box.